# UINavigationController offset from top of screen like phone app does when on a call

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am looking for an elegant reliable way to drop a UINavigationControllers frame down by 20px in order to create a tappable area, much like the native phone app creates when on a call...

[image: example layout]

I have tried things like manually setting the `UINavigationContollers`view`frame` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` but this feels like the wrong thing to do and I would need to write a whole bunch of clauses to layout correctly for iPhone X style screens and rotated devices.

Is there any auto layout I can use to do this elegantly? Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the root view controller a custom parent view controller that determines the tappable area on top, and everything else becomes a child view controller whose view frame is now up to you.

[image]

Comment: Added screencast showing that the result is in line with your specifications. Note, however, that the size of the area at the top would still need to be adjusted for a "notched" display.